# OpenGL multi-texturing error: can't access every texture in samplers

Tags: opengl, textures, glut

I'm trying to send two textures to a fragment shader but it doesn't seem to work. Only one texture can be accessed from the sampler in the shader.

Here is what I'm doing in my code

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(p,"fbo_texture"), 0);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_back);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(p,"back"), 1);

render stuff
```

However if I add `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);` after the last uniform, it works. Also if I specify `GL_TEXTURE1` then `GL_TEXTURE0`, in that order, it's also good. What am I missing?

Edit *

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo_texture);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(p,"fbo_texture"), 2);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_back);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(p,"back"), 3);
```

Works...
A problem with GL_TEXTURE0 apparntly

Comment: What is "it" that's working? What does your fragment shader look like?

Comment: not working : black screen or accessing only one texture and working : full compositing ok

Answer (score 0):

I see that you called one of your textures `fbo_texture`. I assume, that this is a render-to-texture color attachment of a FBO then.

In that case make sure that you bind the texture only after you unbound the FBO for rendering, and vice versa.

Comment: That's what I thought at first but the fbo is unbounded when this piece of code is executed